# Leaflet JS Cluster Marker cancel click event

Tags: javascript, html, maps, leaflet

I've been struggling to cancel the click event that occurs when clicking on a cluster in leaflet. So when I click on a clustered pin the map zooms in. I'd like a custom popup to appear or at least have some way of making sure the map doesn't zoom in when I click on the clustered pin.

I've tried various tricks that I remember such as

```
layerMakers.on('clusterclick', function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();

    L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
    return false;
});
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the problem. Note I've left out all my attempts from this just to make it easier to play with.

http://jsfiddle.net/LzUkF/28/

Any answers gratefully received.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to set the `zoomToBoundsOnClick`-option of the `L.markerClusterGroup()` to false: http://jsfiddle.net/LzUkF/29/